# Struct of Matrices C

Tags: c, matrix, struct

I have this struct:

```c
typedef struct {
    int n;
    bool **a;
    bool **b;
    bool **c;
} matrices_struct;
```

Then I want to assign a matrix a for a given struct:

```c
void multiplyMatrix(int n, int numOfThreads, bool a[n][n], bool b[n][n], bool c[n][n]){
    ...
        matrices_struct *ms = malloc(sizeof(*ms));
        ms->a = a; //doesn't work
...
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: These types don't look compatible: the `a` parameter to the function is a single big chunk of memory that's accessed in a row/column manner, but the structure assumes it's a pointer to an array of pointers to bool.  This will take some refactoring.

Comment: Why do you need a `struct` if you are just passing all the individual parameters anyway? I think we need more information about what you are doing.

Comment: because I need to pass it as an argument on the thread creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have managed to solve this problem like this:

struct:

```c
typedef struct {
    int n;
    bool *a;
    bool *b;
    bool *c;
} matrices_struct;
```

function:

```c
void multiplyMatrix(int n, int numOfThreads, bool *a, bool *b, bool *c){
    ...
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfThreads; i++){
        matrices_struct *ms = malloc(sizeof(*ms));
        ms->n = n;
        ms->a = a;
        ms->b = b;
        ms->c = c;

        ...
        }
    } 
}
```

function call:

```c
...
    bool a[size][size];
    bool b[size][size];
    bool c[size][size];

    fillMatrix(size, a);
    fillMatrix(size, b);
    multiplyMatrix(size, numOfThreads, *a, *b, *c);
...
```